# Use ternary operator in boost lambda

Tags: c++, boost

How do I do the following?

```
vector<int> vec(100);
boost::iota(vec, 0);
static int counter = 0;
boost::for_each(vec, 
    cout << constant(left) << constant(setw(5)) 
         << _1 * 2 << (++var(counter) % 5 == 0 ? "\n" : " "));
```

My error message is:

```
error: value of type '...'  is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
```

Comment: Are you really stuck with such an ancient compiler that you *need* to use Boost lambdas instead of real (compiler-supported) lambdas? Also, I'd go so far as to say that `for_each(x, cout ...` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Use `if_then_else_return`.